# HDD sata bad contact

Tags: sata, contacts, sata-to-usb, usb-to-sata

i have upgraded my laptop with ssd and now i have old HDD. I've bought usb-sata adapter and connected it to my disk. System recognizes controller itself, but no disks are found in system. I tried to press contact with my finger, and it works fine. So something is weird with sata contacts. I tried to clean contacts with alcohol, tried to put paper, but no success.

Took another hdd and it works fine. Thinking further... HDD's have same 2'5 inch form factor, but different in sizes. Problematic hdd has smaller height, does this matter?
What to do with my HDD and usb-sata adapter? It is useless, because need to keep finger while copying files.
Here's the photo of HDDs, disk on the top is problematic:[HDD picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gNuo.jpg)

Comment: Go back to the store where you purchased the adapter, ask to return it, and see if they have one that works.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the drive you took out to me based on the fact that the other drive works just fine.  Jury rigging it with rubber bands might help. :)  That is what I would probably do if I couldn't identify the short.  That adapter you have is mighty useful and on Amazon, they are 14 dollars.  I hope you didn't spend a lot. :|

Answer (score 0):

Your photo doesn't really show what's wrong, but you could attempt putting a small amount of weight on the connector, like an empty glass (or anything else non conducting), to recreate what you did with your finger.
Do secure the object in place with a bit of tape though. The host HDD will vibrate slightly, and this might be enough to knock off the weight over time.

Also make sure you COPY rather than MOVE files over, so the dodgy host drive doesn't do any write operations when it potentially loses connection again.

I wouldn't consider the SATA to USB adapter useless by the way, they're incredibly useful copying stuff over (as you are attempting right now) and for diagnostics.

Comment: Still I don't really know, i've bought usb-sata adapter online. Probably i should go to offline store and ask consultant to get adapter that works with my strange hdd

Comment: I would still attempt to copy your files off of it. Apart from fairly expensive data recovery services, service departments of electronics stores don't generally bother saving your files. But perhaps they can have a look at it and suggest a solution, asking alone won't hurt I suppose.